# Create boxes of uniform size around image and text with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to create boxes of uniform size around images and text with HTML/CSS?

I'm trying to create a row of boxes like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pquTE.png but I've no idea where to start.

I've tried to make the boxes list items in an inline unordered list:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class = "projbox">
    <img src="example1.jpg" width="141" height="200" />
    <p>This is text</p>
    <p>This is some more text</p>
    <p>more and more text</p>
  </li>
  <li class = "projbox">
    <img src="example2.jpg" width="141" height="200" />
    <p>This is text</p>
    <p>This is some more text</p>
    <p>more and more text</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li.projbox {
  border: 30px solid #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;

  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

But the box appears horribly malformed and doesn't surround anything more than the bottom left corner of the image, and the paragraph text isn't backgrounded at all.

Should I be using a table instead to store the boxes? Eventually, I want to be able to make the boxes scroll horizontally.

Comment: You're probably going to want to use divs. Give them a set width and then float them left inside of a div element with the same set width.

Comment: Are the images all the same width & height and is that size known?

Comment: No, I'm still debating whether to crop images to the same proportions or to work around that some other way. That's mostly an aesthetic issue though, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

Markup:

```
<ul>
  <li class="projbox">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/330x460" width="330" height="460" />
    <h2>This is text</h2>
    <p>This is some more text</p>
    <p>more and more text</p>
  </li>
  <li class="projbox">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/330x460" width="330" height="460" />
    <h2>This is text</h2>
    <p>This is some more text</p>
    <p>more and more text</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #eee;
}
ul  {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.projbox {
    padding: 40px 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 600px;
    width: 390px;
}
.projbox img {
    border: 1px solid #00f;
}

.projbox h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 0.2em;
}
.projbox p {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0.2em;
}
```

The thing we're playing with is altering the normal display of an unordered list. To do that we need to remove the standard margins and paddings, and apply our own. Some folks use a CSS reset to do this, for example [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). This also uses a `display` value of `inline-block` to create a uniform block. See more [about `display` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

There's another gotcha about "uniform" when it comes to implementing designs of this kind. You have your placeholder text as 3 short lines, which is great, presuming you really have that control. In my experience elements like this tend to get reused, so you'll need to account for what happens if the lines get longer or stretch over multiple lines. You may want to set a height on these boxes. This gets into things that web designers need to know about like the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model).

I've also implemented this as a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artlung/5V65t/

Comment: As an alternate to giving `body` a background colour, you could give the `ul` a background colour and some padding. Also giving the `ul` a property of `display:inline-block;` "shrinks" uniformly around the list items.

Comment: I'd add that jsFiddle to your answer. :) `inline-block` struck me as the right tool for this job too, so +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @JonP and Jordan!

Comment: @artlung inline-block did the trick. I figured something from class would slip past when I start doing projects outside of the classroom...

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `display:inline;` to `display:block;` This will force them to act like block elements instead of inline.

You can see a jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GcFMh/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use floating divs

**HTML**

```
<div class="projbox">
        <img src="example1.jpg" width="141" height="200" />
        <p>This is text</p>
        <p>This is some more text</p>
        <p>more and more text</p>
</div>
<div class="projbox">
        <img src="example2.jpg" width="141" height="200" />
        <p>This is text</p>
        <p>This is some more text</p>
        <p>more and more text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.projbox {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CW7EX/1/

Answer (score 0):

Create a div that contains the box. You can then replicate this div in ANY structure you want (unordered lists, tables, divs, etc.), it does not need to be contained in an unordered list. This will give you added flexibility of where you can place the box.

**HTML**

```
<div id="projbox">
    <img src="..." class="image">
    <div class="text">
        <p>This is text</p>
        <p>This is some more text</p>
        <p>more and more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#projbox {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#projbox .image {
    width: 141px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 30px;
}

#projbox .text {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#projbox .text p {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done something like this for a sidebar on my website:

[1] Make a div (with a background if you would like).

[2] Put your content in it. If you need to give them absolute positions, use position:relative in the CSS, not position:absolute.

[3] And then finally, put your div on your web page however you want, such as position:fixed or position:absolute, etc.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="yourimage alt="" />
    <p style="font-size:large;">Some text</p>
    <p>Some text <br /> more text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position:absolute;
    (put your positioning stuff here)
}
```